# Confusion with pointer, slices and interface{} in function arguments in go

Tags: pointers, go, slice, go-interface

I've been reading about how Go passes arguments to functions via pointer vs. value.  I've been reading about the interface type. And I've been tampering with the reflect package.  But clearly, I still don't understand how it all works because of this example code here:

```
package main

import (
  "reflect"
  "fmt"
)
type Business struct {
  Name string
}

func DoSomething(b []Business) {

  var i interface{}
  i = &b
  v := reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem()

  for c:=0 ;c<10; c++ {

    z := reflect.New(v.Type().Elem())
    s := reflect.ValueOf(z.Interface()).Elem()
    s.Field(0).SetString("Pizza Store "+ fmt.Sprintf("%v",c))
    v.Set(reflect.Append(v, z.Elem()))
  }
  fmt.Println(b)

}

func main() {

  business := []Business{}
  DoSomething(business)

}
```

When I run this code, it will print a list of ten Business structs with the Business.Name of Pizza 0 to 9.  I understand that in my example, that my `DoSomething` function received a copy of the slice of business, and hence, the `business` variable in my main function remains unaffected by whatever `DoSomething` does.

What I did next was change my `func DoSomething(b []Business)` to `func DoSomething(b interface{})`.  Now when I try to run my script, I get the run time error of `panic: reflect: Elem of invalid type on` on the line `z := reflect.New(v.Type().Elem())`

I noticed that with `DoSomething(b []Business)`, the variable `i == &[]`.  But with `DoSomething(b interface{})`, the variable `i == 0xc42000e1d0`.  Why is the variable `i` different under these two circumstances?

Comment: Although `DoSomething` receives a copy of the slice, they will still point to the same underlying array. Therefore, any changes made to the slice in `DoSomething` can still have an effect on the `business` slice in your main function. https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: @Gavin I was confused for several days by people making similar claims about how slices are effectively passed by reference as arguments in functions.  What led to that confusion was that in a lot of my experiments, even the smallest of experiments, I had introduced `slice = append(slice, newitem)` in the midst of my code. So I never observed the behaviour of slices being passed by reference, and I was frustrated at how I could be mis-interpreting what everyone was saying.  The pains of learning a new language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugger most likely uses (or at least follows) the default formatting rules of the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package:

> For compound objects, the elements are printed using these rules, recursively, laid out like this:
>
> ```
> struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
> array, slice:       [elem0 elem1 ...]
> maps:               map[key1:value1 key2:value2 ...]
> pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
> ```

In your first case `i` holds a value of type `*[]Business`. So if a value being printed (or inspected) is a pointer to slice, it is printed as `&[values]`.

In your second case `i` holds a pointer to an `interface{}` value, which is of type `*interface{}`. When printing a value of this type, the default `%p` format is used which simply prints the memory address as a hexadecimal value prefixed with `0x`.